# Web API global datetime format for parameter binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api, parameters

I am having trouble with binding DateTime parameters in my application (ASP.NET Web API). I'm more familiar with ASP.NET MVC 4 than Web API. In my old MVC application I had same date format coming in from any client application, so I had a custom `IModelBinder` implementation which used this bit of code to parse DateTime values

```
DateTime.ParseExact(valueResult.AttemptedValue, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", new DateTimeFormatInfo())
```

I need something similar in my Web API project and I have headaches finding the solution. I tried custom `HttpParameterBinding`, but to no avail.

I need to specify the format of date parameters either from body or from the URI (query string) globally.

Comment: What is the type and value of  `valueResult.AttemptedValue` exactly? What is your problem?

Comment: my problem is that I have a model with the datetime property in my action method (web api) which has an [FromUri] attribute and the datetime property does not get bound correctly, because of the different format coming from the client application. @SonerGönül